# Steps needed for random walk to reach "the other side" of the sphere

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Suppose I start with $x_0$, a normalized vector in $d$ dimensions, and get $x_{i+1}$ by moving in a random direction on surface of sphere. What is expected number of steps until I first see $\langle x_0, x_k\rangle<0$?

More precisely, suppose entries of $z_i$ are standard normal normalized to have $E[\|z\|^2]=s$, and we have

$$\hat{x}_{i+1}=x_i+z_i$$

$$x_{i+1}=\hat{x}_{i+1}/\|\hat{x}_{i+1}\|$$

[image]

For instance, in $d=100$, $s=1$ distribution of dot products of $x_k$ and $x_0$ looks like this:

[image]
[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/math.SE-sphere-walk.nb)

This value indicates how long it takes to "forget" which side of the plane you started on, and I want to know if there's a simple dependence of "time to forget" on $d$ and $s$. For instance in simulation above with $d=100,s=1$ it's somewhere between 5 and 20

**Motivation:**

This would give a way to prove of "triangle equality for cosines" which is needed for a different application ([background](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430305/triangle-equality-for-cosine-similarity-in-high-dimensions))

Comment: "movement in random direction", if the size of the step is enough small, can be approximated very well using the central limit theorem. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294841/probability-distribution-of-the-distance-after-n-random-jumps-in-a-plane)